# Current Location Issues

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import Foundation
import Darwin

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

func getLocation ()-> CLLocation! {
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    var x = locationManager.location
    println(x.coordinate.latitude)
    println(x.coordinate.longitude)
    return x

}
```

I believe this function, getLocation(), is where the issue in my code is.

```
//Other variables and other actions have been set up here that are irrelevant to the problem within the code.

var wS:CLLocationCoordinate2D! = nil
var carParked:Bool = false
var currentCoord:CLLocation!

override func viewDidLoad() {
//I have set up map, annotation, etc. in viewDidLoad and have tested    that they all work perfectly fine.
}

@IBAction func pinButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    carParked = true
    var currentCoord = getLocation()
    wS = currentCoord.coordinate
    annotation.coordinate = wS
    map.addAnnotation(annotation)

    }

    @IBAction func carFound(sender: AnyObject) {

        carParked = false
        map.removeAnnotation(annotation)
        wS = nil

}
```

One of these two buttons, pinButtonPressed or carFound would be the second most likely place for the error.

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
```

What I want the code to do is whenever pinButtonPressed is pressed the annotation will be placed at the user's current location and stay there. In order to remove the annotation one would press the carFound button. Then, after the carFound button is pressed following the first annotation placement, one should be able to press pinButtonPressed again, and the annotation should be placed wherever the user is, even if they have moved. The issue is the first time pinButtonPressed is pressed, the annotation does call the getLocation() function, finds the current location, and sets this as the annotation coordinates and places the annotation, then I remove the annotation using carFound; however, after that I move my current location and press the pinButtonPressed function again, and the annotation is placed where it was the original time, not where I had moved to. I have placed two print lines to print the coordinates the getLocation() function is returning, and these coordinates are always the same as the first coordinates retrieved since the simulation began to run, no matter where I move my current location to and press the pinButtonPressed button. I believe I am overlooking something obvious, and was wondering if anyone had any ideas to help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the delegate ([CLLocationManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html)) methods of the location manager. Use the method:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: AnyObject[]!) {}
```

In this you should update the position.